# Extracting URL link using re.findall string matching

Tags: python, string, url, extract

I want to extract the following from the below URL: `326/4050/98D32716-2756-404D-9E27-DB02D71BF62D.`

```
class="text-primary font-weight-bolder text-left" href="/salg/info/326/4050/98D32716-2756-404D-9E27-DB02D71BF62D"
```

I have tried this but it is not working:

```
re.findall(r'https?://[^\s<>"]+|www\.[^\s<>"]+',link["href"])
```

Please anyone with some helpful guidance?

Comment: Not working = what? What if you were a doctor and a patient came to you saying "my body isn't working"?

Answer (score -1):

please let me know if it worked for you:

```
import re

string = 'class="text-primary font-weight-bolder text-left" href="/salg/info/326/4050/98D32716-2756-404D-9E27-DB02D71BF62D"'

x = re.search(r'class="text-primary font-weight-bolder text-left" href="/salg/info/(.*)"',string)
print(x.group(1))
```

output:

```
326/4050/98D32716-2756-404D-9E27-DB02D71BF62D
```

a good page to try regex online is [regex101](https://regex101.com/)